# How to create a column based on an updated record change?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Using SQL Server 2017**

I have the following table.

```
UserId OrderId Color
1      a1b2     Red
1      c1d2     Blue
1      e1f2     Green
```

How can I create a column based on the color being updated

```
UserId  OrderId  Color   UpdatedColor
1       a1b2     Red     Null
1       c1d2     Blue    Null
1       e1f2     Yellow  Yellow
```

For example, if the color got updated to `Yellow` from `Green` I want the `UpdatedColor` column to record that change.

Comment: Your results simply make no sense to me at all.

Comment: What do you mean "based on the colour being updated"?

Comment: `Alter table [something]` and add the new column. Then you will have to update that column everty time someone changes the color of the thing only you right now...

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry about that. Please take a look at the example I provided.

Comment: Use `Alter` first then update

Comment: Sounds like something you should be handling in your `UPDATE`. i.e. `SET UpdatedColor = Color`

Comment: It can be a trigger to update UpdatedColor column, but to be honest I'm not getting what's the point if Color column will have that record anyway?

Comment: If you want the UpdatedColor to record the change to Yellow from Green, why does your example results show Yellow in both  columns (Color and UpdatedColor)?  Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `TRIGGER`

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_TempTable_Update 
ON TempTable AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE t 
    SET t.UpdatedColor = d.Color
    FROM TempTable t inner join deleted d ON t.UserId = d.UserId

END
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but i guess theres no point using trigger as the table already has the same column as backup and on update it is like just one more set value to update. Op's query doesnt seem to be critical so as to use a trigger its just an assignment work i guess.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you could look into change data capture.  This will allow you to track if a column value has changed multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer the below sample query

```
    Alter Table T1
    Add Column 'Updated_column' 
    varchar(20)
    DEFAULT NULL;

  Update table t1 set color=new_color, 
     updated_column =new_color
   where user_id=1 and order_id='e1f2'
```

Comment: It is MSSQL. ALTER TABLE [T1] ADD [Updated_column] VARCHAR(255);

Comment: I wrote it as a sample perhaps you need logic right ?